# How many Facebook API calls am I making with this line of code?

Tags: facebook, api

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.limit(100).fields(name,books)&access_token=##############

I believe it is 1.  But in the facebook documentation it says, batch requests api calls are calculated as if they were many individual calls.  Since field expansion is also a "batch request", I am confused how they calculate.

I believe the number of calls will either be one of the following :

1.  1 - line of code

2.  100 - number of friends

3.  100 * (1 + 1) = 200 - 1 each for name and books

Can you please tell me how to calculate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one - it's not a batch request unless you're actually creating a batch of requests per the batch request API documentation (which you're not here; here you're just making one 'call' asking for 100 friends' data)

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for the simple answer "1".  And for clarifying this is not considered as a batch call.